# uiwebview sometimes load the fileURLWithpath sometimes not

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I am loading pdf file from Documents folder using `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strURL]` sometimes it loads the pdf sometimes not and giving the **error**

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL was not found on this server." UserInfo=0x16ff0b40 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/mobile/Applications/0C7AFF53-2328-4C19-B0EB-58EDC7E20B61/Documents/31Oct14-05:17:13pm.pdf, NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/mobile/Applications/0C7AFF53-2328-4C19-B0EB-58EDC7E20B61/Documents/31Oct14-05:17:13pm.pdf, NSLocalizedDescription=The requested URL was not found on this server., NSUnderlyingError=0x16ff3570 "The requested URL was not found on this server."}

I have tested both in iOS7 and iOS8 devices. Unable to solve the issue. could anyone please guide me through. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its happening because in iOS 8 on every run of app directory name changes and I am making path by using `NSHomeDirectory`.

And `UIWebView` not finding the correct path where file exitst.